# Why are Muslims allowed to eat camels but not horses?

Tags: halal-haram, food, animals

I've been told that Muslims are allowed to eat camels but we're not allowed to eat horses. Why?

I thought the reason why they couldn't eat horses was to do with the fact that people use them as a form of transport (well, they did in the prophets time). But camels were also used as a form of transport, so why can we eat them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Horse meat

Actually horse meat is halal: [Is horsemeat Halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26047/17163)

Ahadith such as the following

> Narrated Asma':  We slaughtered a horse during the lifetime of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and ate it. -- Sahih al-Bukhari 5519 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5519); also Sahih Muslim 1942 a [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/34/54))

leads scholars to declare that one can eat horse meat.  For example:

> The majority of scholars are of the view that it is permissible to eat horses, because of the sound ahaadeeth that have been narrated concerning that. -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/70320)

With a consistent fatawa given by [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=86085).

Mufti Ebrahim Salejee instead described it as *There are two opinions of it being halaal and being makrooh. Hence, it is safer not to eat it* at [Mufti Online](http://muftionline.co.za/node/4666), and likewise did Mohammed Tosir Miah at [Darul Ifta Birmingham](http://daruliftabirmingham.co.uk/horse-meat-in-hanafi-fiqh/).

### Camel meat

There's ahadith indicating permissibility of eating camel, e.g.:

> Chapter: (Performing) wudu’ after eating camel meat:  Jabir b. Samura reported: A man asked the Messenger of Allah ... **Should I perform ablution (after eating) camel's flesh? He said: Yes, perform ablution (after eating) camel's flesh.** ... -- Sahih Muslim 360 a ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/123))

And fatawa describe the technicalities of performing wudu after eating camel (e.g. [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/7103), [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=198553), [AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/6464.html)).  See also: [Does eating camel's meat break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9039/does-eating-camels-meat-break-the-wudu)